# How to set up a anchor on stellar?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-sdk, anchor, postgres

As I working on stellar Blockchain, can anyone guide me on how to create an anchor on stellar? and How it will give a withdraw amount in fiat currency & which protocol is it used to convert cryptocurrency to fiat value? I am used [this](https://blockchain.oodles.io/dev-blog/stellar-anchor-set-up/) tutorial to set up an anchor peers ut failed to start 1st Bridge Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial you are using is out of date: the architecture it describes, including the bridge server, were part of a compliance protocol that was [deprecated in 2019](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/pull/420).

For up-to-date info on setting up an anchor service, see the Stellar documentation, which walks through two different architectures that correspond to two different anchor models:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/anchoring-assets/